# Video preview in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, video, video-capture

I have a webcam capture app and I'm trying to implement a video preview in my WPF UI.  Capturing happens in a C++ DLL.  I have a current solution but I'm not too happy with it.  The main goal is that the video preview in the UI doesn't interfere with the C++ DLL much, as it has to compress the video frames and write them to disk.  I won't be able to display every frame, because the compression is fairly CPU-intensive.

My current video preview solution is:

- An Image control is used in my window, and its Source attribute is data-binded to a BitmapSource called VideoPreviewSource
- I set up a System.Threading.TimerCallback to update my preview.  The timer callback function dispatches to a thread which can update the UI (using this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke) which calls UpdatePreview()
- UpdatePreview() asks the C++ DLL for a video frame.  The call to the DLL puts the image's raw data in byte[] _rawImageData, which I allocate once in my window's constructor.
- UpdatePreview() then sets VideoPreviewSource to: BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, pf, null, _rawImageData, width * 4);  Finally OnPropertyChanged("VideoPreviewSource") is called.

It seems like if I make the timer more frequent, garbage collection is called less often and it basically looks like a memory leak.

Any better approach to a video preview?

Comment: Do you need to release the data the C++ DLL provides you?

Answer (score 0):

This [InteropBitmapRenderer](http://silverlightviewport.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/39258#809062) I wrote might help you.  Though I have it hard coded for RGBA (32bit).  Not sure how it works with RGB24 as I think WPF pre-3.51 had issues with 24bit.

If your webcam supports DirectShow, you can use my [WPF MediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/) and use the VideCaptureElement to display a webcam.

Answer (score 0):

I tried an SDK called Ozeki SIP SDK and the followings http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_93-introduction-to-ozeki-voip-sip-sdk-voip.html provide information about how to make a video call.

Hope I could help you.

Regards